# jquery how to hide if no more child

Tags: jquery

Initially I will have

```
<div id="a">
 <div id="a_1" class="toBeHide"> something </div>
 <div id="a_2" class="toBeHide"> something </div>
 <div id="a_3" class="toBeHide"> something </div>
<div>

<div id="b">
 <div id="b_1" class="toBeHide"> something </div>
<div>
```

I will then `$('#b_1').hide()`, now I would say the `#b` have no more child.

My question is how do detect if no more child and hide the `#b` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
   $('#b_1').hide();
if(!$('#b').children(":visible").length){
   $('#b').hide();
}
```

## [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23zbU/6/)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only *hiding* the children, you can check using `:visible`:

```
if($('#b > div:visible').length === 0) {
    $('#b').hide();
}
```

Comment: Your HTMl was incorrect (did not close the first div). Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/23zbU/4/

Comment: Oh, yes, I just copied the html from OP.

Answer (score 0):

try this : If length of children is zero then hide `b_1`

```
 $(function(){
    if($('#b_1').children().length == 0)
    $('#b_1').hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css()` method:

```
$('#b').css('display', function(){
   return $(this).contents().length === 0 ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/84h6e/1/)

---

Things to notice:

1. You don't have closed the wrapper divs.
2. use the `.css()` method and use the `display` property.
3. return the value on count of contents length in the callback of `.css()`
4. so use `$(this).contents().length` it will check for the textNodes too.

For #4 if your markup is something like this:

```
<div id="b">
    something.
</div>
```

Comment: It's bad if `#b` had, for example, `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/23zbU/10/

```
$('#b_1').hide();
var visibleCount=0;
$('#b').children().each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':hidden')){
        visibleCount++;
    }

    if(visibleCount==0){
        $('#b').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#b').show();
    }
});
```

this code actually automates the showing and hiding of `#b`

Comment: What's the purpose of `hiddenCount` variable, if it's value is never read?

Comment: good point, I really don't know, gonna remove it! :D I guess I used it just to clarify what I was doing! @Regent

Comment: Yeah, I understand this, but still... By the way, empty body of `if` looks very strange o_O How about the last edit to `if (!$(this).is(':hidden')) { visibleCount++; }`?

Comment: another good point, I think it's time for me to take a break and drink a cup of coffee! ;)